# What to set as the SMTP server host

Tags: c#, smtp

I am using Visual studio with c#.

I want to send an automatic mail to the user's external email address.

For that I found many useful code snippets.

But in all I have clarify the SMTP.Host like

```
Smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // for example gmail smtp server
```

Write now i am working in the local host only.

So what will be the code for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: smtp is the for the from, not the to. IE, if you're sending from a gmail account you'd want to use the gmail smtp, regardless of the client being yahoo, live, etc.

Comment: @ Snuffleupagus If it is my own website and i am sending from my account then?

Comment: You should have smtp details somewhere from your host, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide which server is to actually sent the email. In your example, Google is sending the email (which also means you need an account there to sent the email from). If you have an SMTP server running on your localhost, then the SMTP-server would be `localhost`.

Basically, the SMTP server (and credentials) refer to the machine that *sends* the email.

Comment: @ Thorsten Dittmar..I got your point. If I am right now using local host i have to give the SMTP port number of my local host. When I transfer it to my test server it should be the SMTP port no of test server...Right????

Comment: I'm not sure whether you get the concept of services and ports. The SMTP port number is always the same - it is standardized (unless you configure the SMTP server to use another port, which is unusual). You need to change the SMTP server name (and maybe the port) only if you actually want to use another server. On Windows, there's not SMTP server by default - this is software you need to install on your own, so I doubt there's an SMTP server on your "localhost". Usually, there's a company-wide SMTP server, so it doesn't really matter whether you're running on your localhost or the test server.

Comment: @ Thorsten Dittmar I edited my question. can you plz visit it once and help me....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741476/need-to-send-mail-to-extrnal-mail-ids-without-having-the-internal-mail-id