# Need to send mail to Extrnal mail ids without having the Internal mail id

Tags: c#, email

I am facing very confusing problem.

In my website all user have there own mail box which can be seen by them when they log in.

I have not assigned then any ids like 123@gmail.com or anything else.

They can send mails to each-other through their names only.

When they send a mail to diffrent user, it is saved as a data row in the database with the help of personid.

Now i want that if a user sends a mail to one other user, it should also automatically send a notification mail to the receiver's external mail id.

I found the related code like

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add("hiral@yahoo.com");
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("hiral@gmail.com");
                    mail.Subject = "Send Email by asp.net code using google or gmail smtp server";
                    string Body = "Hi, I am testing Email function in asp.net";
                    mail.Body = Body;

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address  
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                         ("hiral@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                    //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password  
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                    lblsuccess.Visible = true;
```

It is working perfectly for me now..

Now i need to change the send field in

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("hiral@gmail.com");
```

Because it can be any user without any email id like this.

What can i do for this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the person/sender information from database by personid then put it on a variable list.

```
private class senderInformation{

 private string lastname;
 private string firstname;
 private string email;

}

senderInformation person = new senderInformation();

person.lastname = "Smith";
person.firstname = "John";
person.email= "john@gmail.com";

mail.From = new MailAddress(person.email.toString());
```

Comment: I thought that i can do one thibg that i can send email through the sender's external mail adress to the receiver's mail address...But may be the problem would be that sender need not always have the gmail account..if they have id in other mail providers what changes may be required..?

Answer (score 0):

I would have had the user store a personal email address when they signed up.

Then you could use that email address later when you wish to notify them.

You could then retrieve this email address based on the personid stored in the row in the table.

Comment: I thought that i can do one thibg that i can send email through the sender's external mail adress to the receiver's mail address...But may be the problem would be that sender need not always have the gmail account..if they have id in other mail providers what changes may be required..?